# login via curl and reusing cookie for a second request

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I'm trying to login via curl, and after the login make a second request with the generated cookie. But It doesn't work, I'm not logged in. How can I keep the cookie and reuse it?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

// Define the URL and the data you want to send
$loginUrl = 'https://domain.tld/login.php';
$parseUrl = 'https://domain.tld/start.php?page=user';
$loginVars = array(
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass'
);

// Now we try to login at the page
$login = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $loginVars);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$loginResponse = curl_exec( $login );

preg_match_all('|Set-Cookie: (.*);|U', $loginResponse, $matches);
$cookies = implode('; ', $matches[1]);

// No we download another page while reusing the cookie

$parse = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_URL, $parseUrl);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies);

$parseResponse = curl_exec( $parse );

// Create a DOMDocument for parsing the HTML
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($parseResponse);

// Find the element with an ID of 'username'
$data = $dom->getElementById("username");
echo $data->nodeValue;

curl_close($login);
curl_close($parse);

?>
```

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 4):

This should do the job:

```
<?php

//define the cookie file location, make sure cookie.txt has write permissions
$cookiefile = "/your/path/to/cookie.txt";


// Define the URL and the data you want to send
$loginUrl = 'https://domain.tld/login.php';
$parseUrl = 'https://domain.tld/start.php?page=user';
$loginVars = array(
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass'
);

// Now we try to login at the page
$login = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($loginVars));
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt( $login, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_exec($login);
curl_close($login);

// No we download another page while reusing the cookie

$parse = curl_init();

curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_URL, $parseUrl);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $parse, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$parseResponse = curl_exec( $parse );
curl_close($parse);

// Create a DOMDocument for parsing the HTML
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($parseResponse);

// Find the element with an ID of 'username'
$data = $dom->getElementById("username");
echo $data->nodeValue;

?>
```

**Notes:**

`CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` The name of the file containing the cookie data. The cookie file can be in Netscape format, or just plain HTTP-style headers dumped into a file. If the name is an empty string, no cookies are loaded, but cookie handling is still enabled.

`CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` The name of a file to save all internal cookies to when the handle is closed, e.g. after a call to curl_close.

`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH option.

`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` 1 to check the existence of a common name in the SSL peer certificate. 2 to check the existence of a common name and also verify that it matches the hostname provided. In production environments the value of this option should be kept at 2 (default value).

Comment: Hi Tuga, thank you very much for your solution. I think you have an error on line 41 and 42. it hast to be $parse instead of $login, right? But the script isn't working. :-/ It says "
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/scripts/test.php on line 53" What means, that curl is not on the parse URL, because this div is only on this page. Is there a way to debug it to know what's happening and which url curl tries to parse? The POST form uses the POST / REDIRECT / GET logic. Could this be the problem?

Comment: @emjay Yes, it was an error, I've update the answer and it should work smoothly now, try it now.

Comment: No, it's not working -.- It says " Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/scripts/test.php on line 53" What means, that curl is not on the parse URL, because this div is only on this page. Is there a way to debug it to know what's happening and which url curl tries to parse? The POST form uses the POST / REDIRECT / GET logic. Could this be the problem?

Comment: can you post the html of the page with the `element with an ID of 'username'` ?

Answer (score 1):

For both of your curl requests(`$parse` and `$login`) use the following curl option to set, and get cookie from a txt file.

```
$__COOKIE = "c:/var/temp/cookie.txt";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $__COOKIE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $__COOKIE);
```

By the way, I am assuming your login request is correct.

Comment: I would suggest using [tempnam](http://us1.php.net/tempnam) to get a new tmp file for the session.